# Convert table to JSON array with longtext column

Tags: sql, json, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I'm using mariaDB 10.3, I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE user(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, parameters longtext,  PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

With rows:

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES (1, 'name1', '{"number": 1, "text": "some text"}'), (2, 'name2', '{"number": 2, "text": "some more text"}');
```

I'm trying to write query that returns the table as `JSON` object.
So far I have

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    '[',
      GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('id',id,'name',name,'parameters', parameters)),
    ']'
 ) 
FROM user;
```

But this returns:

```
[
  {"id": 1,
    "name": "name1",
    "parameters": "{\"number\": 1, \"text\": \"some text\"}"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name2",
    "parameters": "{\"number\": 2, \"text\": \"some more text\"}"
  }
]
```

which is not a proper JSON. What should I change to get `parameters` properly formatted?

What I would like to get is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1",
    "parameters": {
      "number": 1,
      "text": "some text"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name2",
    "parameters": {
      "number": 2,
      "text": "some more text"
    }
  }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: (1) If you have just 1 row, what do you expect `GROUP_CONCAT` to accomplish? (2) Please add the desired result to your question. (Use [Edit]).

Comment: You are right, for simplicity I just showed 1 row, but 2 are minimum for this question to make sense. I also added desired result.

Comment: OK. Do I understand correctly that escaped parenthesize (`\"`) is the only thing that separates you from success? Or have I missed something?

Comment: And additional quotation marks (") at the begging and at the end of the parameters entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [`JSON_COMPACT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_compact/) function, which's proper to MariaDB and does not exists in MySQL, might be applied for the `parameters` column

```
SELECT CONCAT(
       '[',
        GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('id',id,
                                 'name',name,'parameters', 
                                  JSON_COMPACT(parameters))),
       ']'
       ) AS "JSON Value"
  FROM user
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f769bcec84464b365a3181142d558b2e)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, this does what i need.

Comment: you're welcome @friltase , welcome to contribution for SO too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JSON_OBJECT** , **JSON_ARRAYAGG(expr)** concept to get your result.
ref: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql_aggregate_functions_json_arraygg.htm

I used  this for one of my project work